# window.opener is null on android chrome (but not in incognito)

Tags: javascript, oauth, instagram, mobile-chrome

I'm opening a new window to complete an Instagram oauth like so:

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, 'Instagram Login', 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

where the `url` is simply the oauth path for the given app. Upon authentication, the following code looks for a function that was defined on the application side to trigger a success callback:

```
if (window.opener && window.opener.foo) {
    window.opener.foo("photo:social:login:success", gon.social_profile);
}
```

This works flawlessly on desktop as well as ios, but android chrome tells me `window.opener` is null, meaning the callback is never reached.

The strange part is that trying the exact same flow on an incognito window in android chrome it works without any issue. `window.opener` points to the original window, and the callback function is successfully fired.

I've already attempted using `parent.window.opener` as well as `top.window.opener` as the code which opens the popup window is inside of an iframe, but it seems to make no difference. is there any reason why android would act differently here?

Comment: in my case, the problem was a way I tested. After several redirects, I had been ending on localhost in popup, so I was manually changing 'localhost' to my laptop IP. It was ok for testing IE inside virtualbox, but didn't work for mobile. I mean it is possible to lost opener somewhere on the way.